# Nearest neighbor search with 2 distance measures

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am working with a dataset for which I was calculating two point correlation with one distance metric using `BallTree` algorithm. Say

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.random((30, 3))
r = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
tree = BallTree(X,metric='euclidean')     
tree.two_point_correlation(X, r)
```

Now, I want to calculate two-point correlation based on two different metrics. Imagine I want to find correlation based on their distances on XZ and YZ planes - group neighbors based on two distances instead of one. Say I want to find correlation within `r1` and `r2` bins based on two different distance metrics say something like

```
r1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
r2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
tree = BallTree(X,metric1=’euclidean2D’,metric2=’euclidean2D’)     
tree.two_point_correlation(X, r1, r2)
```

How can I go about doing that? Goal is to get a contour plot of two-point correlation with r1 and r2 as axes.

**update**

May be it doesn't have to be done at the tree creation level. It could be using loops and creating two different balltrees. Something like

```
tree1=BallTree(X,metric='metric1') #for x-z plane
tree2=BallTree(X,metric='metric2') #for y-z plane
```

And then calculate correlation functions in a loop to get `tpcf(X,r1,r2)` using `tree1.two_point_correlation(X,r1)` and `tree2.two_point_correlation(X,r2)`

Comment: if you just want to project the data into the orthogonal axis 2D planes: `XZ = np.delete(X, np.s_[1], axis=1)`, `YZ = np.delete(X, np.s_[0], axis=1)`

Comment: No not project data... Need to calculate 2D two point correlation function with it

Comment: what do mean by *calculate 2D two point correlation function* then? your data is 3D

Comment: The data is 3D. A 1D two point correlation like the one in the example calculate pairs based on one distance measure. Say distance between two points. I want to group the pairs based on two different distances say distance on xz plane and yz plane ...that is 2D correlation function